# Mysql join query for showing logged in user and followings posts

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables created for a project am working on;

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH9LT.png)

I need help on how to write a mysqli join query that selects post created by USER_ID 1 and all the users USER_ID 1 is following (that is FOLLOWING_USER_ID 2, 3 & 4). 
Currently, logged in user id is saved in a session `$id = $_SESSION['id'];`.

`SELECT * FROM users_post WHERE by_user_id = $id (SELECT following_user_id FROM users_following WHERE user_id = $id) AND by_user_id = following_user_id`

The above code doesn't works :) but I think this is how the code should look like. I will really need your help on how to solve this problem for I am not really good in Mysql join.

Desired output (If ordered by DATE_CREATE desc) and for USER_ID 1
[Desired output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dc8G.png)

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? are you getting an error, or is it just not giving you the desired results?

Comment: Not giving desired results @GharbadTheWeak

Comment: ok, you gave us a screenshot of the data in your two tables, if you give us an example of what the desired result set is we can work on helping you out with it

Comment: Cool! I just want the query to select post created in table `users_post` by USER_ ID 1 and all the users USER_ID 1 is following (that is FOLLOWING_USER_ID 2, 3 & 4). @GharbadTheWeak

Comment: it's still not really clear what you want returned by describing the result set. is there any way you could mock up the desired result set and add it to your original post instead of describing it with words? if you could show the desired columns and the data that would be in those columns that would be great. sometimes it is easy to just mock up the result set in a spreadsheet and sharing a screenshot of that

Comment: Sorry for that, I just edited my question @GharbadTheWeak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aily It sounds like you want to list all of the records from `users_post` where the `by_user_id` is listed as the `following_user_id` for a given user in the `users_following` table. If that is correct, this is what your query should look like:

```
SELECT `up`.* 
FROM `users_post` AS `up`
JOIN `users_following` AS `uf` ON `uf`.`following_user_id` = `up`.`by_user_id`
WHERE `uf`.`user_id` = 1
GROUP BY `up`.`id`
```

If you wanted to also include the posts from `users_post` for the given user, this is what your query would look like:

```
SELECT `up`.* 
FROM `users_post` AS `up`
JOIN `users_following` AS `uf` ON `uf`.`following_user_id` = `up`.`by_user_id`
WHERE (`uf`.`user_id` = 1
    OR `up`.`by_user_id` = 1)
GROUP BY `up`.`id`
```

If this is not your desired result set, please provide more clarification and I'll do my best to help you out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh My! Thank u. But one more thing, How do I also select post created by user_id 1 together with the query @GharbadTheWeek

Comment: @aily I just modified my answer to include what the query would look like if you wanted to display posts from your user as well. I also realized that the query i wrote was selecting everything column from both tables, i modified it so it only shows the data from `users_post`

Comment: Great but I discovered post duplicates for USER_ID 1 @GharbadTheWeak

Comment: @aily all you need to do then is add a `GROUP BY` statement, I just modified the queries in my answer to reflect that

Comment: Am so grateful! @GharbadTheWeak